# Connect to WordPress Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, azure, docker

I created a Docker Container App on Azure that includes a WordPress container and a MySQL container.  When I run the following command:

```
docker run ps
```

I see the two containers.

[image]

I can connect to the MySQL container file system using this command:

```
docker run -i -t mysql:latest /bin/bash
```

If I try to connect to the WordPress container file system using the same command, such as...

```
docker run -i -t wordpress:latest /bin/bash
```

...it doesn't work. Instead it gives me this message:

> Did you forget to --link some_mysql_container:mysql or set an
>   external db   with -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=hostname:port?

It makes sense I guess that it want's me to reference the MySQL container.  But, I've tried various versions of --link and cannot get it to work.

Can someone help me with the Docker syntax?  I just want to make some changes to the file system in this container.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the other side, if you need to run Wordpress container in interactive mode (as you attempted), you'll need to specify the --link like this:

`docker run --link compose990242913_mysql_1:mysql -i -t wordpress:latest /bin/bash`

Answer (score 6):

when you do `docker run ...` you are not connecting to the running containers displayed by the `docker ps` command. What you are actually doing is creating and running additional containers from the docker *images* `mysql:latest` and `wordpress:latest`.

If you want to open a bash shell in the running container named `compose990242913_wordpress_1` then you need to execute the following command:

```
docker exec -i -t compose990242913_wordpress_1 /bin/bash
```

Once you are in that shell, make sure to quit properly by typing the `exit` command or you might leave processes behind in that container.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.  I get the error message "flag provided but not defined: --entrypoint".  I checked docker exec --help and don't see --entrypoint as a valid option.  Any ideas why?

Comment: You might be using an outdated version of Docker. What does `docker version` shows ?

Comment: Client/API is 1.7.0/1.19.  Same for Server/API.

Comment: My bad, `docker exec` does not have the `--entrypoint` option. I edited my answer which still stands